# How do I get the values returned with Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm stuck, I run this query with hibernate, but do not know how to get the values that the query returns.

**Query:**

```
select idMagistrado, count(*) as numeroDemandas from demandamagistrado group by idMagistrado order by numeroDemandas asc limit 3;
```

**DAO:**

```
public Set<Magistrado> get3Magistrado() {
        ConnectionDataBase cdb = new ConnectionDataBase();
        Set<Magistrado> magistrados = null;

        try {
            Query createQuery = cdb.getSession().createQuery("select idMagistrado, count(*) as numeroDemandas from demandamagistrado group by idMagistrado order by numeroDemandas asc limit 3");
            // Here, HELP!
            if (magistrados == null) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (HibernateException he) {
            cdb.catchException(he);
        }
        finally {
            cdb.closeSession();
        }

        return magistrados;
    }
```

And the **result** in de **MySQL console**:

```
mysql> select idMagistrado, count(*) as numeroDemandas from demandamagistrado group by idMagistrado order by numeroDemandas asc limit 3;
+--------------+----------------+
| idMagistrado | numeroDemandas |
+--------------+----------------+
|            3 |              1 |
|            2 |              2 |
|            1 |              3 |
+--------------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The Query object has no method to let me know the values of **idMagistrado** and **numeroDemandas**. I do not know what to do, HELP.

Comment: you just created the query. add `magistrados = createQuery.list();` to your code on your comment line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should know "HQL" is different from "SQL";
when you use HQL, you should query from class (not table).

so if you wanted excute the sql and get result in hibernate:

```
String sql = "select idMagistrado, count(*) as numeroDemandas from demandamagistrado         
group by idMagistrado order by numeroDemandas asc limit 3";
```

you should use the method createSQLQuery (not createQuery) in this way:

```
 List<Object[]> objList = cdb.getSession().createSQLQuery(sql).list();
 for(Object[] objs : objList){
    int idMagistrado = Integer.valueOf(objs[0]);
    int numeroDemandas = Integer.valuesOf(objs[1]);
    System.out.println(idMagistrado + ":" + numeroDemandas);
 }
```

Comment: the method createSQLQuery is for SQL,  createQuery is for HQL;

Comment: Yep, that's what I was looking for. Thank you sooooo much. :3

Answer (score 1):

HQL is an **object-oriented query language**, similar to SQL, but instead of operating on tables and columns, HQL works with persistent objects and their properties.

> Lets assume that we have a database table structure like below :

[image]

> Then the Entity class for each table can be given (Hibernate mapping Java classes to database tables):

**Subject**

```
public class Subject  implements java.io.Serializable {


 private Integer id;
 private String subName;
 private String day;
 private String time;
 private Set subjectHasStuDetailses = new HashSet();


public Subject() {
}
//getters and setters
...
```

**StuDetails**

```
public class StuDetails  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private Integer id;
     private String FName;
     private String LName;
     private String sex;
     private String dob;
     private Set subjectHasStuDetailses = new HashSet();

    public StuDetails() {
    }
    //getters and setters
    ...
```

**SubjectHasStuDetails**

```
public class SubjectHasStuDetails  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private Integer id;
     private StuDetails stuDetails;
     private Subject subject;

    public SubjectHasStuDetails() {
    }
    //getters and setters
    ...
```

In every entity class we can override the default constructor as we need.

Lets assume that our entity classes are in a package named **com.hibernate.entities**. If we need to get all the subjects doing by a selected student then our Hql query can be:

```
Query query = ss.createQuery("FROM com.hibernate.entities.SubjectHasStuDetails shs WHERE "
                + "shs.stuDetails.id= :s_id").
                setInteger("s_id", 32);
 List<com.hibernate.entities.SubjectHasStuDetails> shs = query.list();
    for (SubjectHasStuDetails sh : shs) {
       sh.getSubject().getSubName();
    }
```

As we can see in the given example of Hql query we are referring to entity members of the class which is mapped to the required table.Not referring the table column names.

So in your case also you should refer the mapped entities.

```
SELECT d.member_variable, COUNT(*) AS d.member_variable FROM packagename.EntitityClass  d GROUP BY d.member_variable ORDER BY d.member_variable ASC LIMIT 3
```

> **Update:**

If you are using ***identified relationship***:

**Subject:**

```
public class Subject  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private Integer id;
     private String subName;
     private String day;
     private String time;
     private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<>();
     ...
```

**Student:**

```
public class Student  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private Integer id;
     private String FName;
     private String LName;
     private int age;
     private Set subjects = new HashSet();
     ...
```

**Query:**

```
Query q = s.createQuery("FROM com.hibernate.entities.Subject sub JOIN sub.students s WHERE s.id= :stu_id")
                .setInteger("stu_id", 1);
       List<String> subj = q.list();
    for (String ss : subj) {
        System.out.println(ss);
    }
```

Comment: I understand but, the problem is, in your example your are using a "Non-Identifying" relationship", in my case i'm using a "Identifying relationship", so the 3th table "SubjectHasStuDetails" does not exist. My query is some "especial".